# How can I use Hash map from firebase database in android

Tags: android

```
val usersref = RTDBref.child("users")
    
    usersref.get().addOnSuccessListener { datasnapshot ->
        val datas = datasnapshot.value
        Log.i("datas", datas.toString()) //it returns hash map

        val id = datas.get("Id") //can't use , redline here
    }
```

`datasnapshot.value` returns {Id=userId, uid=uid}. It's a hash map.

So I wanna use `val id = datas.get("Id")`  to get data from a hash map,

But I can't use it because `val datas` is Type of Any? before retrive data from firebase database.

Is there any way to use `get()` method to `val datas` please?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cast.

```
(datas as? Map)?.get("Id")
```

This will tell the compiler to treat it as a map.  If data is not a map, it will set datasMap to null, and the ?. operator will make the entire statement return null in that case.